# Pycharm: cannot import lightfm

Tags: python, pycharm, recommendation-engine

I tried to load the `movie_lens` dataset using the code below

`from lightfm.datasets import fetch_movielens`

running this  i am getting:
`ImportError: No module named 'lightfm.datasets'; 'lightfm' is not a package`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like the `lightfm` package is not installed in your environment. You can check in `File>Project Structure>SDKs` make sure `lightfm` is present in the **Packages** tab of the environment you're using for your project. Otherwise you can add the package from that same window.

Answer (score 0):

since i have already tried many ways and failed,finally i run my python terminal from the default python3.5 saved folder -->for me it is /usr/bin ,then i created a new project in pycharm IDE ,istalled lightfm using pip3 it worked there too ,now i can import LightFM